# Is DIP28S the same as SOP28?

Tags: packages

I am looking at buying a chip holder for a chip that comes in the form of DIP28S according to different datasheets on it. However when I searched for DIP28S chip holders I could only find SOP28 chip holders, and the measurements of them would allow the DIP28S chip to fit in those chip holders. So my assumption would be that DIP28S is the same or very similar package form to SOP28. Am I correct?

Comment: SOP28 is an SMD package while DIP28 is a package with leads, so they are not the same. I don't know what S in DIP28S is supposed to mean. Can you put a link to the datasheet?

Comment: here is the link http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/41215/SANYO/LM8560.html

Comment: Ok! It's SDIP, and not DIPS. SDIP means Skinny DIP. It's a DIP package, 0.3 inches wide.

Comment: Ups, sorry, I've looked better at the datasheet, it's indeed "DIPS", similar to DIP but with unusual metrics. Maybe "DIPS=DIP Sanyo"!

Comment: I think the main difference is that the pins on the DIPS chip are closer together than on a DIP chip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DIP28S could be a "shrink DIP" through-hole package, that is basically a standard DIP x 0.7.

It used to be quite popular in the Asian market (eg. [Fujitsu](http://www.fujitsu.com/downloads/MICRO/fma/pdfmcu/d28pm03.pdf)).

[image]

Also "DIP28S" [has also been used](http://pdf.datasheetarchive.com/indexerfiles/Scans-000/Scans-0014409.pdf) to refer to the "skinny" 300-mil wide 28-pin DIP package to distinguish it from the 600-mil wide package.

[image]

In no way is it the same as an SOP-28 SMT package.

Answer (score 1):

The packages are different, you won't be able to use SOP holder to hold a DIP package. The datasheet shows 1.78 mm pin distance so it is more narrow than the standard DIP which gas 2.54 mm between pins. Therefore, standard DIP socket won't work either.

Answer (score 1):

DIP28 is usually 600 mils wide, with a 300 mil width also very common; the "S" in this package name refers to the fact that it is 400 mils wide as per the mechanical drawing. You will need to find a socket that fits appropriately, rather than the normal 300 mil or 600 mil sockets used for DIP28.

Comment: Not only is the package an unusual 0.4" wide, the pins are on 0.07" centers, rather than the usual 0.1".